# Gears for Hero Cyclone

Tags: gears

I have a Hero Cyclone bicycle that is a single speed. Can I add gears to it? If so, can anyone suggest me a good gear?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. The [Hero Cyclone](http://www.herocycles.com/cyclone#.VdLIQ7PPHtQ) does not appear to have a hanger / mounting holes for a dérailleur. You may be able to install an internal gear hub, but it would likely cost far more than the bike.

You may be able to find something used though.